# Type Hinting in function parameters for User Defined Classes for own Class instance, or a Class not yet interpreted (python)

Tags: python, type-hinting

Imagine:

```
class A:
    def foo(a: A, b: B):
        ...

class B:
    def bar(a: A, b: B):
        ...
```

In this case only the bar function's "a: A" is caught be the python interpreter. The other yield errors. What is the best way of type hinting correctly?

Thanks!